# Issue of Origin Alignment in Tetrahedralization using Tetgen

Tags: 3d, geometry, alignment, mesh, tetgen

It seems that when exporting an `STL` file from a 3D mesh editing program and then using `tetgen` for `tetrahedralization`, there is an issue where the `tetrahedralization` occurs not at the aligned point but rather at the origin (0,0,0). If there is a way to perform `tetrahedralization` without aligning to the origin, please provide guidance, such as `tetgen` option...

I am using `Tetgen` for `tetrahedralization` with the "-p" option. After using Tetgen to tetrahedralize my *.stl mesh, origin of `tetrahedralized` mesh file(*.ele, *.node) is aligned to center.